# How to host R Shiny app using shiny proxy when code is on windows server?

Tags: linux, docker, shiny, server

I have an R shiny app in Windows Server 2019. I want to deploy this app using shiny proxy but it needs docker. Because docker cant run on WS19, I was given a Linux server with docker and shiny proxy installed on it.

Is it possible to have the source code for the app in WS19 while hosting it using shiny proxy/docker in the linux server?

Would it be possible to update the images/containers from ws19? Say I added a new button in the source code. How would WS19 "talk" to the linux server to update the hosted app?

I'm new to this and these were the servers/tech given to me and I can't change our method.

Thanks!